# Controlling digits / rounding as argument in base functions

Tags: r, rounding, r-markdown, digits

In scientific paper writing, values are typically reported as rounded values with one, two or three digits, often depending on the type of value reported. This means that everytime when e.g. including an inline `mean` value in Rmarkdown I have to add `round` to the code.

Thus I am wondering: Is there a way to control number of digits of the output of base functions like e.g. `mean()` as an additional argument within the `mean()` function? Actually this additional argument would also need to conduct rounding.

Obviously there are a number of ways to control the number of digits, e.g. `round(), format()` and `sprintf()` or specifying the number of digits in the global option. I do not want the latter option as I need different numbers of digits within the document.

So, what I want is something like:
`mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789), digits=2)`

which yields the same result as:
`round(mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789)), 2)`

I know, this is kind of silly, as the number of character to be typed is exactly the same in both chunks. For me the key difference would be that I could write `, digits=2)` directly *after* typing the variable and not having to jump to the beginning of the chunk to add `round(` *and* to the end to add `, 2)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a custom function to allow a rounding parameter, for example `round_mean <- function(..., digits = getOption("digits")) round(mean(...), digits)` and then use either `round_mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789))` or `round_mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789), digits = 2)` but that would mean you are no longer using the original base function..

Comment: Or you can write the code in an Rmarkdown document via `kintr` or `pander`, which can take care of this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I know is using forward-pipe operator `%>%` from  `magrittr` package

```
> library(magrittr)
> mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789))
[1] 0.36501
> mean(c(0.34333, 0.1728, 0.5789)) %>% round(3)
[1] 0.365
```

I should also mention, that package `magrittr` is used by another very popular  package `dplyr`, which provides additional functionality for data frame operations. So, when I am using piping, I nearly always write `library(dplyr)`, while `magrittr` stays behind the scene.